# Python Sqlalchemy filter by date range

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have two date picker fields that i want the users to select from date to end date. and i want to display data between the two dates that was selected. From example form date: 2/14/2018 to date:3/15/2018. when the function is called i want to extract and display data between this two dates.

i just need some help with the query to accomplish that.

I am using sqlalchemy to pull data from an mssql db

Here is my code. The two date pickers selectdate and selectdate1 which are then converted to julian dates. convert and convert1, i need some help with the query that does the magic.

```
def bydate_display(request):
    if "selectdate" in request.POST:
        if "selectdate1" in request.POST:
            if "selectaccount" in request.POST:
                selected_date = request.POST["selectdate"]
                selected_date1 = request.POST["selectdate1"]
                selected_acc = request.POST["selectaccount"]
            if selected_date==selected_date:
                if selected_date1==selected_date1:
                    if selected_acc==selected_acc:
                        convert=datetime.datetime.strptime(selected_date, "%Y-%m-%d").toordinal()
                        convert1=datetime.datetime.strptime(selected_date1, "%Y-%m-%d").toordinal()
                        engine=create_engine('mssql+pymssql://username:password@1hostname /db')
                        connection=engine.connect()
                        metadata=MetaData()
                        fund=Table('gltrxdet',metadata,autoload=True,autoload_with=engine)
                        rate=Table('gltrx_all',metadata,autoload=True,autoload_with=engine)

                        stmt=select         ([fund.columns.account_code,fund.columns.description,fund.columns.nat_balance,fund.columns.rate_type_home,rate.columns.date_applied,rate.columns.date_entered,fund.columns.journal_ctrl_num,rate.columns.journal_ctrl_num])
                    #stmt = select([fund, rate]).where (and_(fund.columns.journal_ctrl_num==rate.columns.journal_ctrl_num))
                        stmt=stmt.where(and_         (rate.columns.journal_ctrl_num==fund.columns.journal_ctrl_num,fund.columns.account_code==selected_acc,rate.columns.date_applied==convert,rate.columns.date_applied==convertconvert1))
                        #stmt=stmt.where(or_(rate.columns.date_applied==convert,rate.columns.date_entered==convert1))
                        results=connection.execute(stmt).fetchall()


                        return render(request,'bydatedisplay.html',locals())
```

Comment: Can you give us examples of code you've tried, and what results you're getting or where you're getting stuck?

Comment: Consider combining those nested if statements to a single if statement using the `and` operation: `if "selectdate" in request.POST and "selectdate1" in request.POST and ...:`. Your indentation is also off; if `"selectaccount"` is not in POST, all the variables will be used before assignment. `if selected_date==selected_date:` is just noise.

Comment: Finally, are you looking for `rate.columns.date_applied.between(convert, convert1)`? http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.between

Comment: Thanks, Yes i am looking rate.columns.date_applied.between(convert, convert1). I have applied that but only display the results from the first selected date.

Comment: Thanks heaps lljja Everila its working now.